# Rust: How to add one to a u8 array

Tags: arrays, math, rust, aes, addition

I am working at the AES in CTR-mode for learning purposes and need to add 'one' to the ctr block at the end. But in order to add one i had to convert the result of the previous code (aes_encryption which returned a [u8;16]) to a u128. Now i want to convert this u128 back to an array. Is there a possibility to do so?
My alternative idea was to add one directly to the array using the `split_off()` function of `std::collections::BitVec` which would be simpler and faster i think.

Comment: If all you need is adding one, it's probably easier to [implement that yourself](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4f31368782cf1f57f9e1372f08b68964), rather than converting back and forth to `u128`.

Answer (score 1):

> But in order to add one i had to convert the result of the previous code (aes_encryption which returned a [u8;16]) to a u128. Now i want to convert this u128 back to an array. Is there a possibility to do so?

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=to_*_bytes

Comment: That would be because `to_bytes` makes no sense on a number as it doesn't take *endianness* into account, and thus why -- as listed in the link provided -- numbers have `to_be_bytes`, `to_le_bytes` and `to_ne_bytes` instead.

Comment: Note that presently, rustdoc search doesn't allow wildcards, so that search URL is broken, but it does allow searching based on signature, so this works: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=u128%20-%3E%20%5Bu8%5D